# How to access static file from webapp folder in spring controller?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I am trying to access an ifc file which is in the `webapp` folder.

If I specify the path as below then its working

```
Paths.get("F:\\webapp\\resources\\images\\mag1\\model.ifc");
```

But it does not when I specify the path like

```
Paths.get(".\webapp\resources\images\mag1\model.ifc");
```

As the application is running on a server I cannot give complete path.

Comment: Whats the error message?

Comment: (The system cannot find the path specified)

Comment: I would recommend to add the error message in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use getRealPath() of ServletContext to get the path of the deployed WAR folder structure on the server file system [ServletContext#getRealPath()](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/ServletContext.html#getRealPath%28java.lang.String%29).

Answer (score 0):

The back slash is used with escape for special purpose. 
So when ever you want ""F:\webapp\resources\images\mag1\model.ifc"" fine then "\" should be replace with "\"

Comment: "\" should be replace with "\\"

Comment: i do not want to give complete path F:\webapp\resources\images\mag1\model.ifc i want give like 
  webapp\resources\images\mag1\model.ifc

Comment: webapp should be replace woth "F:\webapp" in your code when accessing wedpage.

Comment: Paths.get("\\webapp\\resources\\images\\mag1\\model.ifc"); this will not work

Comment: webapp should be defined in environmental variable for what it is referring it is E drive or F drive.